# IIS Hosted B2B WCF REST Authentication

Tags: wcf

The WCF service provides a REST endpoint which is accessed by a customers business process.
I want to have a security system that verifies a user name and password from the incoming request to make sure it is only from this customer.

From exploring this topic it seems like Basic Authentication is a close fit but it needs a custom HTTPModule and an Entry in the web.config for it to work in a 'B2B fashion'.

My expectation being:
1)The HttpModule will handle the authentication and I can leave the IIS configuration as is. i.e. I don't have to turn on Basic Auth at site level using IIS manager.

2) My test Postman 'No Auth' POST against the service should work when Auth is off and fail 401 when Auth is on. (on and off being controlled by the HttpModule and its web.config associated values)

3) With the HttpModule Auth on, enabling Basic Auth in Postman for the POST should make it work again.

So if Basic Auth is not the best option please advise.

My problem is that as soon I add the HTTPModule entry  to the 'System.Web' element in the web.config the site goes 500 when accessed.

The HTTP module  and Web.config follow. (The HTTP module is cobbled together from various sources.)

Source:
    HTTP Module

```
public class BasicAuthHttpModule:IHttpModule
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {

        app.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
        app.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
        app.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(app_AcquireRequestState);
        app.PostAcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(app_PostAcquireRequestState);
    }

    private void app_AcquireRequestState(object o, EventArgs ea)
    {
        HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)o;
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        ctx.Response.Write(" Executing AcquireRequestState ");
    }

    private void app_PostAcquireRequestState(object o, EventArgs ea)
    {
        HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)o;
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        ctx.Response.Write(" Executing PostAcquireRequestState ");
    }

    private static void SetPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Validate the user and password
    /// which are stored in Web.Config
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        if(Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            Log.Debug($"Auth attempt User {username} password {password}");
        string sUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReceiptUser"];
        string sPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReceiptPassword"];
        bool result = username == sUser && password == sPassword;
        if(Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            Log.Debug("Checkpassword result is " + result);
        return result;
    }
    private static void AuthenticateUser(string credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                Log.Debug($"Authentication Attempt credentials {credentials}");
            }

            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));

            int separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
            string name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
            string password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);
            if(Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                Log.Debug($"About to Check Password username{name} password{password}");
            if (CheckPassword(name, password))
            {
                if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                    Log.Debug($"Password Checked OK username{name} password{password}");
                var identity = new GenericIdentity(name);
                SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(identity, null));
            }
            else
            {
                if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                    Log.Debug($"Password check failed return 401 username{name} password{password}");
                // Invalid username or password.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // Credentials were not formatted correctly.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Log.Error("Credentials not correctly formatted");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Extract the Authorization Header.
    /// If Header exists parse it  and authenticate it
    /// If it doesn't exist then check if basic auth is turned on.
    /// If it is turned on throw a 401.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Log.IsDebugEnabled)
            Log.Debug("Authentication Hit");
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                Log.Debug($"OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest request.Headers[\"Authorization\"] is {authHeader} ");
            var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

            // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
            if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
            {
                if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                    Log.Debug("OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest about to authenticate basic user parameter  " + authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool basicAuth = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BasicAuth"]);
            if (!basicAuth)
            {
                if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                    Log.Debug("OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest request.Headers[\"Authorization\"] is null and basicAuth is not turned on in Web.Config ");
                return;
            }

            if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
                Log.Debug("OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest request.Headers[\"Authorization\"] is null ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }

    // If the request was unauthorized, add the WWW-Authenticate header 
    // to the response.
    private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Realm = "WCCReceipt";
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxxxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="OriginID" value="19" />
    <add key="Diag" value="true" />
    <add key="Receiptuser" value="xxxx"/>
    <add key="ReceiptPassword" value ="xxxxx"/>
    <add key="BasicAuth" value="false"/>
    <add key="CheckPayableTicket" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
  **<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="xxxxx.BasicAuthHttpModule"/>
      <!--<add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="WebHostBasicAuth.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule, xxxxx"/>-->
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>**
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingJSON" receiveTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="xxxxx.xxxxx">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="xxxxx.Ixxxxx" />
        <endpoint address="JSON" behaviorConfiguration="RESTJSONEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJSON" name="JSON" contract="xxxxxx.Ixxxxx" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="RESTJSONEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp  defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <file value="Log/Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger[%thread] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <logName value="NetVendor" />
      <applicationName value="NetVendor" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %logger[%thread] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </root>
    <category name="DesktopLogger.Form1">
      <priority value="ALL" />
    </category>
  </log4net>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the website is hosted in the IIS, the `Basic authentication` is provided by the `BasicAutenticationModule` of the IIS. and it always authenticates the client with the windows account of the server. therefore, I don’t think our custom basic authentication module will work.
Here is another solution for custom authentication in WCF Rest web service, wishing it is useful to you.
[How to Implement custom authentication in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378352/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-wcf-service/57388728#57388728)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I have been trying a lot of different solutions. No luck. Maybe I am over thinking it. You say basic authentication is against the windows account of the server. If we gave these credentials to the one and only user then just enabling Basic Auth in IIS (and disabling Anonymous) should do it?